# [react]: useMemo returns first element when passed an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, react-usememo

Here's the sample code

```
export default function App() {
  const [links] = React.useMemo(
    () => ['hello', 'world'],[]
  )
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => console.log(links)}>console</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked, i get following in console

```
hello
```

My question: since it returns the first element, i'm unable to map over `links` array. is it even the way I should be using `useMemo`? note that the array i passed is for example and the elements could get bigger than just a simple string.

Comment: `() => [['hello', 'world'],],[]` , in your code, links = 'hello'

Comment: and why did you use `React.useMemo()` to init your links, just use `useState`

Comment: try `const links = React.useMemo(() => ['hello', 'world'],[]);` instead, because if you destructure the returned array to grab its first value, you get the first value, which is `hello`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was, as pointed by [@Andrea Giammarchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800218/andrea-giammarchi), the destructuring of links in lvalue

Following code fixes the problem:

```js
- const [links] = React.useMemo(
+ const links = React.useMemo(
```